# @EnableFeignClients not found with openfeign 2.1.1.RELEASE

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I am creating a spring boot project with following versions

> spring-boot-starter-parent: 2.1.3.RELEASE
>
> java.version: 1.8
>
> spring-cloud.version: Greenwich.SR1

and I have included openfeign starter dependancy in pom

@EnableFeignClients on Application class is not found.
it was available in 1.4.4.RELEASE version.

Has something changed?
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/single/spring-cloud-openfeign.html#netflix-feign-starter still talks about including @EnableFeignClients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still there. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/master/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/EnableFeignClients.java

The package is different. It is in `org.springframework.cloud.openfeign`.

Comment: Thank you, works, there was some problem with local m2, after refreshing, I was able to compile